# How to immediately detect a change on a collection of inputboxes

Tags: jquery

For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, [jQuery's change()-event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

I got a form with multiple inputboxes and i'd like to do something as soon as the user changes the value of any of those inputboxes.

Is there an event that is not deferred until the inputbox loses focus, but fires immediately when the user changes a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like binding multiple events:

```
 $("input[type='text']").bind("change blur keyup mousedown", function () {

    // your foobar here

 });
```

or only keys and mouses ;)

```
 $("input[type='text']").bind("keydown mousedown", function () {

    // your foobar here

 });
```